# jQuery Mouseup only triggers on second click

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I have a checkbox that is being selected by label. I am then adding a class of selected to the parent li. Once this happens I want to count the instances of '.gquiz-correct-choice .gquiz-indicator' on the page.

The count is only updated if I click a second time.

I've tried adding 'return false'. Binding the click & mouseup, using change instead of mouseup, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.gfield_radio li label', function(event) {
   jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
 });

 jQuery('.gfield_radio li label').mouseup(function(){
    var numItems = jQuery('.gquiz-correct-choice .gquiz-indicator').length;
    jQuery('.pts').html(numItems + '/20');
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first click seemed to be 'hijacked' so I decided to add a timeout to run the count after.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.gfield_radio li label', function(event) {
 jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    setTimeout(
        function() {
          var numItems = jQuery('.gquiz-correct-choice .gquiz-indicator').length;
          jQuery('.pts').html(numItems + '/20');            },
      500);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

on errors jquery event are not fired just try to print to console.
In this codepen you see both events are fired simultaneously (http://codepen.io/f7o/pen/vKxKXX)

```
 jQuery('.clickit ul li').click(function(event) {
   console.log('added class')
   jQuery(this).parent('ul').addClass('selected');
 });

 jQuery('.clickit li').mouseup(function() {
   console.log('count')
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because mouseup is executed before click.

A way to solve your problem is:

```js
// global variable to test if mouse
var mousedUpFired = false;

function doMouseUp() {
  var numItems = jQuery('.gquiz-correct-choice .gquiz-indicator').length;
  jQuery('.pts').html(numItems + '/20');
}


jQuery(document).on('click', '.gfield_radio li label', function(e) {
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');

  // check if mouseup has been triggered
  // if yes, execute what contained in your old mouseup event handler
  if (mousedUpFired) {
    doMouseUp();
  }
  // reset global variable
  mousedUpFired = false;
});


$(function () {
  jQuery('.gfield_radio li label').mouseup(function(e){
    // set global variable on mouseup and do nothing
    mousedUpFired = true;
  });
});
```

Comment: The example isn't working? Neither is mine with the updated code.

Comment: @cdb I verified the problem on my computer. I do not have your HTML but only your js, so I discovered this: mouseup is fired before click. This means only on the second time you get the updated values. I hope this could help you

Comment: @cdb The order is: mousedown --> mouseup --> click. This fiddle could help you: https://codepen.io/mudassir0909/pen/eIHqB

Comment: This makes more sense. The first click seems to be already used, so I need to add on to that somehow.